# How can you remove "now playing" from the new control center in Big Sur

Tags: macos, customization, control-center

Is it possible to remove the "Now Playing" (Music) section of the Control Center in Big Sur?

The mac is my work machine, and I never (can't) listen to music when I work, it's not a big deal, but it's always nice to be able to fine tune a machine setup, and for me that would mean removing this.

What I've tried:
I found this help from Apple about customisng the Control Center: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchl50f94f8f/mac

But when you get to the relevant setting, it simply says "Now Playing is always available in the control centre" You can optionally show it in the *menu bar* but can't get it out of the control centre as far as I know.
[image: Dock and Menu Bar window in System Preferences]

Edit: Update to note that this is unchanged in Monterey.
Edit: And also unchanged in Ventura

Comment: My honest expectation is that this is not currently possible, (which would be a valid answer) but I've asked the question in case the setting becomes available later, or there's an app or  something that allows more fine-grained configuration than system preferences.

Comment: One more thing to add to my meters long list of things that Apple does and annoys me to no end! I'm choosing the path of least resistance at the moment so this is the final answer I'm going to get for now and I don't like it. I hope Apple dies sooner rather than later. I hope Ubuntu Mobile gets a comeback. AOSP is better than Apple, even stock Android is better than Apple. At least I can choose my own development OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that it is possible to edit the portion of Control Center that includes Now Playing. Just as on iOS, that is included in the top portion that cannot be changed. I haven't heard of any apps or utilities that are able to change how the Control Center is laid out, either. If you want the ability to change that, perhaps file some feedback with Apple.

Comment: Thanks - fingers crossed at some point in the future this question can get updated with a different answer.